# Как сделать merge двух строк?

Tags: python, строки

У нас есть:

```
is_merge('localhost', 'local', 'host')
True
is_merge('localhost', 'lacol', 'tosh')
True
is_merge('localhost', 'loc', 'hos')
False
```

Согласно этому условию, мы должны сделать Merge строки:
Я попробовал сделать конкатенацию, однако мне нужно именно собрать строку из букв.

```
def is_merge(s, part1, part2):
    if (part1+ part2 == s):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Как сделать сборку строки и сопоставление строки полученной из part1 и part2 и сопоставить её с исходной строкой s, при условии, что в строке могут встречаться пробелы.

Comment: Уточните, вам нужно проверить, что строка в первом аргументе состоит из тех же букв (и в том же количестве), что и 2 и 3 аргумент вместе?

Comment: Т.е. проверяем без учета пробелов? Пробелы могут быть в любой строке или только в первой?

Comment: В буквах, то есть я могу набрать 'l o c a l' & 'h o s t'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если перефразировать условие как "проверить, что первая строка состоит из тех же букв, что и 2 и 3 строки вместе взятые", то можно решить, например, отсортировав буквы:

```
def is_merge(s, part1, part2):
    return sorted(part1 + part2) == sorted(s)
```

Возможны и другие варианты решения, например посчитать сколько каких букв в каждой строке и сравнить:

```
from collections import Counter

def is_merge(s, part1, part2):
    return Counter(part1) + Counter(part2) == Counter(s)
```

**Обновление.** Если нужно сравнение без учета пробелов, можно перед сравнением отфильтровать из строк все кроме букв:

```
def is_merge(s, part1, part2):
    s, part1, part2 = (list(filter(str.isalpha, item)) for item in (s, part1, part2))
    return sorted(part1 + part2) == sorted(s)
```

Для второго варианта аналогично (причем не обязательно преобразовывать итератор, который вернул `filter`, в список):

```
from collections import Counter

def is_merge(s, part1, part2):
    s, part1, part2 = (filter(str.isalpha, item) for item in (s, part1, part2))
    return Counter(part1) + Counter(part2) == Counter(s)
```

Comment: Часть, которая нормализует строки для сравнения, можно в виде параметра вынести: `is_merge = lambda s, *parts, normalized=sorted: normalized(s) == normalized(''.join(parts))` Затем достаточно только поправить определение `normalized`, не касаясь `is_merge` кода, если формат допустимых входных строк изменится, например: `normalized = lambda s: Counter(filter(str.isalpha, s.casefold()))`